# Integrate Quickbooks Desktop with my application in Java

Tags: java, quickbooks

I tried to integrate Quickbooks Desktop with my application in Java.

I have installed the Quickbooks Desktop trial version and Quickbooks Web Connector. I have created a web service for the sample code given in Quickbooks Desktop's development documentation.

My QWC file.

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<QBWCXML>
   <AppName>Example Development Service</AppName>
   <AppID></AppID>
   <AppURL>http://localhost:8080/qbwc/services/QBWebConnectorSvcSoapImpl</AppURL>
   <AppDescription>Example Development Service</AppDescription>
   <AppSupport>http://locahost:8000/wsdl</AppSupport>
   <UserName>loyola.a</UserName>
   <OwnerID>{57571caa-e934-4f14-b3bf-dfdbacdd273a}</OwnerID>
   <FileID>{dc25fda6-bce2-493b-9e04-a1560bde96e4}</FileID>
   <QBType>QBFS</QBType>
   <Style>DocWrapped</Style>
   <Scheduler>
      <RunEveryNSeconds>600</RunEveryNSeconds>
   </Scheduler>
   <IsReadOnly>false</IsReadOnly>
</QBWCXML>
```

While Web connector calling authenticate method, I am getting the below error in QWClog file even my username and password are correct,

```
QBWebConnector.SOAPWebService.do_authenticate() : QBWC1012: Authentication failed due to following error message.
Object reference not set to an instance of an object
```

Please help me for further steps to do.